# Smoothness of distance function induced by Finsler metric

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, regularity, geodesics, finsler-geometry

Consider $\mathbb R^N$ endowed with a smooth Finsler metric $\phi:\mathbb R^N\times S^N\to (0,+\infty]$. The smoothness assumption are both on $\phi(x,\cdot)$ (being at least $C^{2,1}$) and $\phi(\cdot,p)$ (being at least $C^1$). Let's fix a subset $E\subset\mathbb R^N$, whose boundary $\partial E$ is a smooth hypersurface, i.e. having codimension 1. I'm considering the signed distance function $d_E$ from $E$, induced by $\phi$, that is
$$d_E(x)=\inf_{y\in E} \text{dist}(x,y)-\inf_{y\notin E}\text{dist}(y,x),$$
where the geodesic distance between two points is the usual $$\text{dist}(x,y)=\inf\Big\{ \int_0^1 \phi(\gamma,\dot\gamma)\text{d}t,\ \gamma\in W^{1,1}([0,1]),\ \gamma(0)=x,\gamma(1)=y \Big\}.$$
As D. Yang pointed out in the comments, usually this function is not differentiable. My question is if one could ensure nonetheless that there exists $\nabla d_E$ just on $\partial E$.

Comment: First, $d_E$ is not smooth on $E$ itself. Second, it's not necessarily smooth on for a Riemannian metric, since $d_E$ is not smooth at a point where there is more than one minimizing geodesic from $E$ to that point.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Are there sufficient conditions to ensure that in a suitably small neighborhood of the boundary $\partial E$ the distance function $d_E$ is smooth? It seems difficult to belive.

Comment: Use the square of the distance function.

Comment: @DeaneYang: If $\partial E$ is a smooth hypersurface, then isn't $d_E$ as defined $C^1$ in a neighborhood of $\partial E$, at least in the Riemannian case?

Comment: @WillieWong, isn't this not true if $E$ itself has codimension $1$ or more?

Comment: @DeaneYang: oh, I had assumed that E has full dimensions (inferred based on the definition of the "signed distance" given by the OP). Perhaps the OP should specify what is meant by $E$ being "smooth enough".

Comment: I changed the question, hoping to clarify a bit. Thanks for the insights.

Comment: OK. I missed the "signed", and @WillieWong's point was valid. I think you're assuming that $E$ has nonempty interior with smooth boundary. I'm not sure what the answer is, but you should be able to compute 1-sided directional derivatives of $d_E$ using the definition of $\operatorname{dist}$.

Comment: Yes, that was known. Thanks for the help anyways.